# InvalidOperationException: The view 'Login' was not found. After publishing

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I get the following error after publishing a self-contained x64 to an IIS server.

InvalidOperationException: The view 'Login' was not found.

When looking at the folder I can see that there is no view folder there (the published folder) In similar threads people suggest that the Views/* is included in the project.json file, I can not find any file with that name. Is that file replaced by the publishing profiles, I have tried to add

```
<ItemGroup>
  <File Include="Views/*">
     <publishTime>06/14/2018 00:26:42</publishTime>
  </File>
</ItemGroup>
```

to the publishing profile without any luck.

I am using asp.net core 2.2.2, and VS17.

To give more context. When someone who is not logged in tries to access the Home/Index (default site) they get redirected to the action (Login, under the AccountController using return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account").

I have the following structure on my project:

```
Controller/AccountController
```

Which has the function

```
 [HttpGet]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
 {
       \\Logic
       Return View();
 }
```

Within a folder called Views I have folder called Account, which contains a .cshtml file with the name "Login.cshtml"

I must add that everything is working when I am running the server in VS17.

The error occurs after I deploy it as a self-containing build.

Would a database error cause an error like this? (Some error within the function making it invalid or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it had to be build using the dotnet.exe publishing command. When I did it through VS17, the views were not included.

Answer (score 0):

By default, views are compiled and embedded into the published application, hence why there's no published views folder. The error message is not complaining about the physical lack of the view, but rather the complete lack of the view in the compiled application. More likely than not, you're referencing the `Login` view incorrectly and it cannot be found by a conventions-based search. However, there's not enough information here to fully evaluate that.

Comment: What information do you need? I have a redirect in the Home controller, which redirect to Login with the help of the following function. return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account"); Is that not legal?

Comment: Specifically, how you're returning or utilizing this particular view, since that's what the error is about. ASP.NET Core uses a conventions-based approach to locating views, and if you break that convention, then it doesn't work. You may need a full path to the view for example, but we have no visibility into that.

Comment: When I run the code locally everything works without any issues, it happens after I have published it to the IIS. The controller has the name Account, and the view it self is called Login. The cshtml file is under a folder View/Account/Login.cshtml.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details, I don't know what is needed, sorry in advance if that is not enough.